# How to make JPanel transparent in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have multiply smaller JPanels which are then added to a bigger JPanel which is the same size as JFrame. Now I want to make those smaller JPanels transparent and the image I have added to the bigger JPanel showing in the background. I tried using setOpaque(true) on the smaller JPanels but it does not show the image that I have added to the bigger JPanel. I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: To make it transparent, it should be `setOpaque(false)`. (If this answers your question, I could turn it into an answer, but I'd rather close the question - it's more of a typo, and likely a duplicate)

Comment: Yep it works, I constantly tried to make it true instead of false.

Comment: In some cases you need to set a transparent background color to a component by `panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));`

Comment: @c0der, that is not the way to do transparency. That will break the painting chain and cause painting artifacts. See [Backgrounds With Transparency]() for more information and solutions if you need to use partial transparency.

Comment: Tank you for your comment. I added it because `setOpaque(false)` doesn't do what I expected it to do when say I want a transparent button on a jpanel.

Comment: @c0der, With a button you can just use `setContentAreaFilled(false)` for transparency. Also I forgot to include the link in my above comment. Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/).